# Where can I find the definition of scala.Any and scala.AnyRef?

Tags: scala

I wanted to jump into the source of Any to see how some methods had been implemented, but I see it is not included in the scala-library-src, and neither is AnyRef (value types and Nothing are, however). I'm curious, how and where are Scala object base types implemented?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/src/library-aux/scala/Any.scala` and `/src/library-aux/scala/AnyRef.scala` contain `trait Any` and `trait AnyRef`.

Comment: As pointed by the readme of library-aux, those files are not really compilable (the source files are there mostly so that those types appear in the scaladoc). There are not such classes as `AnyRef` or `Any` at runtime. On the jvm, the short story is that `AnyRef` is mapped to `java.lang.Object`, `AnyVal` has no single mapping (mapped either to one of the primitive types - such as `int` - or its boxed version - such as `java.lang.Integer` depending on the context. `AnyRef` = `AnyVal` | `AnyRef`, and thus has no single direct mapping either. OVersimplified, but hopefully you get the idea.