# Scala's class hierarchy

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Questions on Scala's class hierarchy:

1. In the IntelliJ IDE, I am looking for the implementation of `Any` and `AnyRef`, but they are not there.
   Where are they defined and how can I see their code?
2. I read the following in "Programming in Scala"

> The only case where == does not directly call equals is for Java's
>   boxed numeric classes, such as Integer or Long. In Java, a new
>   Integer(1) does not equal a new Long(1) even though for primitive
>   values 1 == 1L. Since Scala is a more regular language than Java, it
>   was necessary to correct this discrepancy by special-casing the ==
>   method for these classes.

Hmm... but isn't `==` final? How did they make a special case for Java's numeric classes?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13010984/where-can-i-find-the-definition-of-scala-any-and-scala-anyref May be helpful for the first question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Any`, `AnyRef`, `Null`, and `Nothing` do not actually exist; they are included to make the type system complete, but they have no real representation. You can find [a reference in Scala's repository](https://github.com/scala/scala/tree/99a82be91cbb85239f70508f6695c6b21fd3558c/src/library-aux), but as it says, these do not actually compile and exist for documentation and bootstrapping purposes only. Scala's 3 `Any*`s are actually all `java.lang.Object` in the compiled bytecode.

Additionally, the primitive value classes (`Int`, `Long`, etc.) are all defined `final abstract`, meaning that they also do not actually exist. All of their methods are abstract.

In order to make everything look neat and tidy, and more importantly, work, it is the compiler's job to fake the existence of these types and perform magic to make it all stick together. This is what allows `==` to do null-checking and properly handle value types even though it's `final`, as the compiler is doing magic around it. In the case of `new java.lang.Integer(5) == new java.lang.Long(5)`, it boils down to `scala.runtime.BoxesRuntime.equalsNumNum(new java.lang.Integer(5), new java.lang.Long(5))`.

Comment: That's a lot of magic, was there a reason why not making it more straightforward? Also, you are saying that the compiler actually breaks the final rule, is it not a problem (for someone who looks at the reference code, although it is not compiled)?

Comment: @rapt In my eyes this *is* rather straightforward. In Scala-land we have a sound, *normal* type system with bottom type `Nothing`, top type `Any`, the primitives as (almost) normal subclasses of `AnyVal`, the primitive ops like `+` and `/` as normal abstract methods on the primitive classes, etc. The magic happens when this system needs to be squished onto the JVM and its limitations.

Comment: I am not asking on the design of the ideal system, but on the implementation. Was there any problem to implement real Any, AnyRef, as well as concrete Int, concrete Long, etc?

Comment: @rapt `==` needs to be marked `final`, because otherwise I could do this: `trait Oops extends Any { override def ==(sucker: Any) = ??? }`

Comment: Yes I was not suggesting not to make `==` final, but only saying that the compiler breaks this rule. It would not create a compilation error; the problem might be to the reader of the code who may assume it's honestly final.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It made things much clearer.

Answer (score 6):

It is quite normal for languages to have "magic" parts like this. Parts that cannot be described in the language itself.

The obvious example: you can either declare a superclass, or you can not declare a superclass, in which case the superclass is `AnyRef`. So, how do you write `Any`, a class that has no superclass? Well, you can't. You could extend the language and allow programmers to write classes with no superclasses, but then you could no longer guarantee that `Any` is the *only* such class, and thus your inheritance hierarchy would no longer form a lattice. But, the type checking and type inferencing rules *depend* on the inheritance hierarchy being a lattice.

So, the only sane choice is to have a definition of `Any` that cannot actually be expressed in the language itself.

This is not peculiar to Scala: you have the same problem with Java's and Ruby's `Object`, for example.

Actually, Scala has a lot *less* such "magic" compared to other mainstream languages … and a significant fraction of the "magic" it *does* have is for platform compatibility with the underlying host ecosystem (Java for Scala-JVM, ECMAScript for Scala.js, CLI for the abandoned Scala.NET, CoreFoundation for a hypothetical Scala-macOS, etc.).

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your wording. Superclass has at least two meanings: parent class and the ultimate parent class (like Object in Java) - which one did you mean? Also, what it wrong with making `Any` a subclass of java.lang.Object, and if I get you right you are concerned that `Any` would still have a parent - then why not disable it through the compiler. Anyway, it's still possible to access `Object` from Scala, so `Any` is not really the ultimate superclass.

Comment: @rapt `Any` actually is the ultimate superclass. The type system is designed such that `Any` is above `Object`. You can prove this by running `implicitly[Object <:< Any]` and `implicitly[Object =:= Any]` in the REPL. The second errors because the compiler cannot prove that `Object` is equal to `Any`, and the first succeeds because the compiler *can* prove that `Object` is a subtype of `Any`. If you do `implicitly[Object =:= AnyRef]` you'll also find that those are exactly equal.

Comment: You are right, I neglected that fact. So Any & AnyRef cannot really compile according to their reference code anyway. Any idea what would be the reason for the non-concrete value classes (Int, Long, etc)?

Comment: 1) These types exist to abstract the difference between primitives and boxed primitives (`Int` will be `int` if it can, `Integer` if it must). The conversions are hidden by magic. 2) How would you implement primitive ops in a class when you can't actually use primitives (i.e. how do I define `Int.+`?)? When the compiler sees you doing primitive ops it makes it into an actual bytecode instead of a method call.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your example at the 2nd point. There are no primitives in Scala so why would you need to think about them? Aren't primitives implicitly converted to some Ops class when I operate on them?

Comment: @rapt: There are no primitives in Scala, but there are primitives in at least one of the platforms that Scala is implemented on (JVM), and you want to implement Scala using primitives in order to gain performance. However, in Scala, everything is an object, but on the JVM primitives are not objects. The way this is done in the Scala-JVM implementation is to implement them as primitives but fake their object-ness in the compiler … again, this is not something you can express in Scala, because it is simply impossible to express the idea of something not being an object in a language where …

Comment: … everything is an object.

Comment: @Jörg W Mittag I understand. Thank you for the enlightening answer and the following explanation.